# Why doesn't append() work correctly with a dictionary created via zip() with empty lists as values?

Tags: python

Dictionary d works fine, as expected,

```
In [335]: d={1:[], 2:[]}

In [336]: d[1].append('word')

In [337]: d

Out[337]: {1: ['word'], 2: []}
```

But dz, which looks identical to d, doesn't work correctly.

```
In [339]: dz=dict(zip([1,2],[[]]*2))

In [340]: dz

Out[340]: {1: [], 2: []}

In [341]: dz[1].append('word')

In [342]: dz

Out[342]: {1: ['word'], 2: ['word']}
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Python 2.6.5

Answer (score 3):

This is a common Python gotcha: `[[]]*2` creates two references to the same empty list. You want `([], [])` or `[ [] for _ in xrange(2)]` (suitable for long sequences of empty lists).

Simpler example that represents your `zip` code:

```
In [1]: dupl = [[]] * 2

In [2]: dupl[0].append(1)

In [3]: dupl
Out[3]: [[1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> c = a
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is a
True
>>> a is c
True
```

`is` demonstrates that your unexpected case is due to having two ways of referencing the *same* object.

```
>>> d={1:[], 2:[]}
>>> d[1] is d[2]
False
>>> dz=dict(zip([1,2],[[]]*2))
>>> dz[1] is dz[2]
True
```

If this is not intended behavior, I would probably write

```
>>> dz = dict( (k, []) for k in [1, 2] )
>>> dz[1] is dz[2]
False
```

or (assuming new enough Python, and this is what you want)

```
>>> import collections
>>> dz = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `d`, the values of the dict are initially two separate empty lists. In `dz`, they are the same empty list.

Answer (score 0):

`[[]]*2` creates a list which contains the same list twice, not a list containing two different lists.

```
x=[[]]*2
print x[0] is x[1]
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator used to copy elements makes a *shallow copy* instead of a real copy.  Essentially, it is duplicating the reference to the same empty list and a change to either reference changes the contents of the same, shared list.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to what you're eventually going to do with your `dict` but if you want to have the default content in a dict be a certain value, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['a'].append(3)
print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [3]})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the answers. Using copy() solves the problem, indeed.

```
In [1]: import copy

In [2]: udict = lambda a,e: dict(zip(a,[copy.copy(e) for _ in xrange(len(a))]))

In [3]: dzx = udict([1,2],[])

In [4]: dzx[1].append('word')

In [5]: dzx

Out[5]: {1: ['word'], 2: []}
```